# List all faces of a mesh visible from the view of the camera Opengl

Tags: opengl

as the question suggests I have to identify all the faces that are visible from the camera's view and do some processing with them. I have a single mesh.

I am thinking of giving individual faces a different colour and do a blind render. This will enable me to read the FBO. Then I have to traverse all the pixel and find the unique faces by their colour.

Are there any faster way?

Comment: for simple convex objects the normal vector can be used to determine visibility, just dot it with the forward vector from the view matrix

Comment: actually the above trick will give you every triangle facing the camera but triangles that are completely occluded by other triangles will also be in the list.

Comment: I am dealing with non convex objects

Comment: This works with any object convex or not, what it won't do is give you occlusion information, so if 1 triangle completely occludes another, both will still be in the list. I should not have put convex in there. It would even work with scenes.

Comment: Oh right! I need to exclude the triangles that are occluded by other triangles.

Comment: Once you have a list of triangles facing the camera, take a page out stencil shadows and use extrusion to determine visibility which is greatly simplified since the triangles must be completely contained.

Comment: Then wrap the whole works up in a compute shader.